# How to list all the ScalarMapple colormaps in Matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib, colormap, scalar

Whenever I do interpolation plot, I noted that not every colormap in Matplotlib.cm is ScalarMappable. I wonder what is the proper way to get the full list of colormap which is ScalarMappable?

I manage to get the full list by reading the trackback message as following. But I don't think it is a good idea.

```
def get_scmaps():
    try:
        from traceback import format_exc
        plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap="xyz")
    except ValueError:
        result = format_exc()
        search_str = "supported values are "
        if search_str in result:
            smaps = (result.split(search_str)[-1])[1:-1].split("', '")
    return smaps
```

Comment: if you just want the sorted list of all colormaps, you can use `sorted(plt.colormaps())`

Comment: [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)? what are you really trying to do?